# Using pandas.DataFrame.query with dataframes that have special characters in column names

Tags: python, pandas

I noticed that from version 0.25 spaces are allowed in column names when using `pandas.DataFrame.query`, i.e. those column names should be surrounded with backticks. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a b':[1,0,1,1,0,0],
                   'c d':[1,0,1,1,0,0],
                   'e f':[0,0,0,0,1,0]})

print(df)

   a b  c d  e f
0    1    1    0
1    0    0    0
2    1    1    0
3    1    1    0
4    0    0    1
5    0    0    0

q = "(`a b` == 1) | (`c d` == 1) | (`e f` == 1)"
df = df.query(q)

print (df)

   a b  c d  e f
0    1    1    0
2    1    1    0
3    1    1    0
4    0    0    1
```

It works fine but my columns may contain ampersand, plus or other special characters. They don't seem to be supported at the moment:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a b+':[1,0,1,1,0,0],
                   'c | d':[1,0,1,1,0,0],
                   'e & f':[0,0,0,0,1,0]})

print(df2)

   a b+  c | d  e & f
0     1      1      0
1     0      0      0
2     1      1      0
3     1      1      0
4     0      0      1
5     0      0      0

q = "(`a b+` == 1) | (`c | d` == 1) | (`e & f` == 1)"
df2 = df2.query(q)

print (df2)
```

Last print gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\scope.py", line 188, in resolve
    return self.resolvers[key]
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 914, in __getitem__
    return self.__missing__(key)            # support subclasses that define __missing__
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 906, in __missing__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'a_b_'
```

Is there any workaround for this or a different way to build filter condition for dataframe? I wanted to define a function returning dynamic filter as string.

Comment: I would recommend cleaning up your column names, unless you specifically need them to have those characters.

Comment: Unfortunately I need them.

Comment: Why do you need them? It does not make sense to have column names like that.

Comment: You can bypass the column names and using `DataFrame` methods: `df2[df2.eq(1).any(axis=1)]`

Comment: Because users will upload the file and will want labels to be generated as per columns names which can be anything. So it can be any number of columns and any column names.

Comment: Used @Erfan suggestion as a workaround

Answer (score 0):

actually pandas supports unicode symbols in column names, it should be working.
please try this method:

```
set1 = df2['a b+'] == 1
set2 df2['c | d'] == 1

print(df2[set1 | set2])
```

worked for me at your test data